# remove empty array in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

[here is my code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duketopmost/xpohpLsg/)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl1", MyCtrl1);

function MyCtrl1($scope) {

    $scope.block = new Array();

    $scope.block[0] = new Array();
    $scope.block[0].push("111");
    $scope.block[0].push("112");
    $scope.block[0].push("113");
    $scope.block[0].push("114");
    $scope.block[0].push("115");

    $scope.block[2].length = 0;

    $scope.block[3] = new Array();
    $scope.block[3].push("111");
    $scope.block[3].push("112");
    $scope.block[3].push("113");
    $scope.block[3].push("114");
    $scope.block[3].push("115");


    $scope.block.filter(Boolean);

    console.log($scope.block.length.toString());

}
```

[["111","112","113","114","115"],["111","112","113","114","115"],**[]**,["111","112","113","114","115"]]

how to remove the empty array
Thanks help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
$scope.block.splice(2,1)
```

The first parameter specifies the index of the "block" array.  The second parameter specifies how many items to remove starting at that index.

Comment: @user3382559 This will only work if you know in advance where the item to remove is (and won't remove multiple items at once).

Comment: @JLRishe Good ~ Thank you for reminding me, I will pay attention to these

Answer (score 3):

`Array#filter` does not modify the array it's called on. It returns a new array.

Also, `Boolean([])` is `true` so that won't work here.

Do this:

```
$scope.block = $scope.block.filter(function (arr) {
    return arr.length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmLmrqrq/

Comment: Thank you for your swift response to solve my problem, thank you